# C++ Find if integer exits in a column of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

If I have

```
int x = 5
```

and

```
M = | 3 4 5 |
    | 5 2 1 |
    | 5 6 2 |
```

How can I check if a specific column contains x? So that I get false when I check the second column. And I get true if I check first or third column.
In MATLab I would write,

```
if find(M(:,2)==x)>1
  disp('true')
else
  disp('false')
end
```

To check whether x is in second column or not.
I was wondering if there is a similar way in c++.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the C++?

Comment: I am more familiar with Matlab where I would write:

if find(M(:,2)==5)>0
  disp('true')
else
  disp('false')
end

However, I dont see a simple way of adressing specific columns or rows in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
bool colContains(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &matrix, int x, int col) {
    for(int y = 0; y < matrix.size(); y++) {
        if(matrix[y].size() < col) continue; //Make sure we don't go out of bounds
        if(matrix[y][col] == x) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How can you propose a solution if you don't even know which datasctructure is he using for the matrix?

Comment: @JaviV By giving him some example code to show the general algorithm. For example, switching to an STL list implementation would just be a matter of using an iterator instead of a counter.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for giving an answer despite my poor question. I managed to proceed using your answer.